# Forge Vewer v7 - Search in Default UI

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, forge

I'm trying to use Autodesk.InViewerSearch extension in Forge viewer v7, but I keep getting error **that new Autodesk.Viewing.A360ViewingApplication('forgeViewer', options) is not a constructor.** Does this extension work in viewer v7? If I set new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(htmlDiv, config3d) my app works, but Autodesk.InViewerSearch is not registered.

**This is my Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer**:

```
Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function onInitialized() {
        // var randomId = makeid(36);
        var documentId = 'urn:' + urn;

        console.log(documentId);
        var config3d = {
            loaderExtensions: { svf: "Autodesk.MemoryLimited" },
            extensions: [
                'Autodesk.DocumentBrowser',
                'Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore',
                'Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsGui',
                'Autodesk.VisualClusters',
               
                'Autodesk.InViewerSearch',
                'ToolbarExtension',
                'BoundingBoxExtension',
            ],
            inViewerSearchConfig: {
                uiEnabled: false,
                relatedItemsTab: {
                    enabled: true,  //If false, the tab is hidden.
                    displayName: 'This Item',
                    pageSize: 20
                },
                loadedModelTab: {
                    enabled: true,  //If false, the tab is hidden.
                    displayName: 'This View',
                    pageSize: 50
                }
            }
            
        };

        //viewerApp = new Autodesk.Viewing.A360ViewingApplication('forgeViewer', options);
        //viewerApp.registerViewer(viewerApp.k3D, Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D, config3d);
        // viewerApp.loadDocumentWithItemAndObject(documentId);
        //viewerApp.registerViewer(viewerApp.k3D, Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D, config3d);
        //viewerApp.loadDocument(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);

        var htmlDiv = document.getElementById('forgeViewer');
        viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(htmlDiv, config3d);
        var startedCode = viewer.start();

        if (startedCode > 0) {
            console.error('Failed to create a Viewer: WebGL not supported.');
            return;
        }

        console.log('Initialization complete, loading a model next...');
        var documentId = 'urn:' + urn;

        Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);

    });
```

**My options file looks like this**

```
 var options = {
        env: 'AutodeskProduction',
        getAccessToken: getForgeToken,
        api: 'derivativeV2' + (atob(urn.replace('_', '/')).indexOf('emea') > -1 ? '_EU' : ''),
        /*memory: {
            limit: 1024 // in MB
        }*/
    };
```

**And in my index.html I've included:**

```
<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found the `A360ViewingApplication` class nor the `Autodesk.InViewerSearch` extension in the Forge Viewer codebase so I'm afraid these have been removed in version 7. Let us know what exactly you wanted to achieve with the extension, I'm sure there is a different way of implementing that goal with the viewer version 7.

Comment: Well, I want to implement something like this: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/tutorials/search-in-default-ui/  but it seems that in v7 this extension doesn't exist. Now I see that in my Model Browser extension I have some search functionality, is that maybe the same as this extension from v2?
Thank you for your answer Petr.

Comment: I see. Yes, the search functionality was moved to the Model Browser so you don't have to worry about any other extensions: https://imgur.com/a/9pPSFZq.